# Implementing a router in Vue 2 project

Tags: vue.js, http, vuejs2, routes, vue-router

I'm in the process of converting my Vue project from V3 to V2 to make better use of BootStrap. I've started copying my files over, but I'm running into some errors. Most recently, eslint tells me that 'app' is unused. I've tried ignoring this error, but that has not worked as the webpage does not load. I suspect there could be more going on here. Here's my router where the error occurs:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import MovieDetail from './views/MovieDetail.vue'
import ReviewMovie from './views/ReviewMovie.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/movie/:id', component: MovieDetail },
    { path: '/movie/:id/review', component: ReviewMovie}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  template: '<App />',
  components: {
      App
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

And here's my main app:

```xml
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <header>
    <router-link to="/">
    <h1><span>Horror</span>Hub</h1> 
    </router-link>
  
  </header>
  <body>
      <router-view />
  </body>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Seems like there are many issues. Please create a codesandbox

Comment: @Mr_Happy What console errors/warnings do you see?

Comment: @TJ Hi, I've made a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-grass-46wdl

Comment: This isn't just a router issue, all of your components are written in Vue3 syntax

Comment: @TJ Yep, I'm trying to convert the project. It seems like there's more changes than I realised, so I won't try to use Vue 2 any more as learning both syntax is confusing for a beginner and I'm likely to just get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unused variable

Since `app` is not used, you can just remove it to resolve the ESLint warning:

```js
// const app = new Vue(/*...*/).$mount('#app')
   ^^^^^^^^^
new Vue(/*...*/).$mount('#app')
```

But that's not the cause of the page not rendering.

### `template` option

I suspect one of the problems is your usage of the `template` option without the [runtime compiler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) enabled in your project (and you should see a warning in the browser's console log). However, you don't really need the `template` here, and you could use the [`render` option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#render) instead:

```js
new Vue({
  /*
  template: '<App />',
  components: {
      App
  },
  */

  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### Composition API

Your components are using *Composition API*, which requires a plugin in Vue 2:

1. Install the [`@vue/composition-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) plugin:

   ```bash
   npm install -S @vue/composition-api
   ```
2. In `main.js`, setup the plugin:

   ```js
   import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'
   Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
   ```
3. Update all the Composition API references to import from `@vue/composition-api`:

   ```js
   // import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
   import { ref, onBeforeMount } from '@vue/composition-api'
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/converting-vue-3-to-vue-2-rc4fc?file=/src/main.js:223-305)

Comment: Hi Tony, unfortunately that hasn't worked. I think there's definitely an issue with the rendering though. You can see the code here, if you're interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-grass-46wdl

Comment: @Mr_Happy One of the issues is your project is missing `@vue/composition-api`. See updated answer.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks for your help! Very informative answer